# What opportunities are there for me if I hold an undergraduate degree in translation?

Tags: graduate-school, undergraduate, translations

I'm finishing an undergraduate degree in translation this year. Actually, the focus was on learning business English and I took more classes related to linguistics, the literature and history of Eng speaking countries than actual translation classes.

I would like to apply for a different graduate degree. Something that would open more opportunities for me because I know that this degree won't get me hired (maybe if I knew more languages but I don't). I'm also not sure translation is the path I wanna take.

I'm kind of stuck in terms of what I want to do. I've always been interested in languages, it was the only thing I was good at when I was a kid. As an adult I've realized that there are many people who are far better at them than me. Now I regret that I didn't try to learn more skills when I was younger.

I value hands-on experience the most, something practical where I can apply my skills. My undergrad subjects have been nothing but boring theory that I gradually forget overtime. I have no idea what kind of graduate degree I could apply for. I think my choices are very limited. I cannot simply switch to a completely unrelated field, no uni would accept my application because I do not meet the requirements. I've tried searching online for some degrees but I haven't found anything. I live in central Europe.

Does anyone have any idea what opportunities I have if I hold an undergrad degree in translation? My initial plan was to expand my language skills in Korean and German so I can be fluent in 4 languages. But I'm not sure if this will get me anywhere in life in terms of employment opportunities. Even though I'm currently learning both, it will still take me a lot of time to reach fluency.

Comment: This might depend on where you are and where you want to study. Needs more information.

Comment: I live in Slovakia. I've been looking for different schools around Europe or some scholarships outside of Europe because my financial situation doesn't allow me to just simply move abroad to whatever country I want to. I prefer Austria or Germany the most tho. But my degree has to be in English.

Comment: Any local linguistic people/workshops you could ask?